# How to configure NetworkManager on a remote host without GUI?

Tags: networking, network-manager, systemd-networkd

I have a remote host running ubuntu desktop 22.04 and the default network renderer is NetworkManager.
how can I set permenant configuration to the interfaces managed by NetowrkManager ?
for example with networkd, I just edit the .yaml files and do a netplan apply.
but the same doesn't work with NetworkManager.

are there any files that I can edit or should I change my renderer to be networkd ?

Comment: There is "nmcli" command-line tool for controlling NetworkManager.

Comment: I share your consternation with Network Manager.  I use netplan unless I have no other choice.  If you must use NM, you will need to get very familiar with `nmcli`.  It's painful but not impossible.

Comment: thanks for your comments 
I just disabled NM and enabled networkd, much easier for me to configure this way.

Comment: I actually wanted to run NetworkManager GUI remotely, and it did not work when starting the vncserver as normal user. When I ran vncserver as root (not sure how secure it is, or is there a better way, it was on an internal (corporate) network and ran it only temporarily) then I could see the NetworkManager applet in the "system tray" and could run its configurator app.